# How to get column datatype ,through datagridview, from ANY table and insert data into the table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview

I have a huge problem. Right now I have a Windows Forms application in C# that lets me login into any PostgreSQL DB and view the DB table contents in a datagridview. What I need to accomplish now is find a way to read the datatypes from the datagridview column values and a find a way to insert new, correct data in the tables.

Here's the code I have for reading the data, if it might help. (I put table names in a listbox and display their data upon selecting them)

```
public void readdata()
    {
        DataTable tabulusaraksts = new DataTable();
        string connectionstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" + "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", serveris, port.ToString(), user.ToString(), password.ToString(), database.ToString());
        ncon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring);
        string tab = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        NpgsqlCommand listfill = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables where schemaname != 'pg_catalog' AND schemaname != 'information_schema';", ncon);
        adapter.SelectCommand = listfill;
        adapter.Fill(tabulusaraksts);
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "tablename";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "tablename";
        listBox1.DataSource = tabulusaraksts;
    }

        public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable tabula = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = false;
        string tab = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        NpgsqlCommand showtable = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from " + tab + ";", ncon);
        adapter2.SelectCommand = showtable;
        adapter2.Fill(tabula);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabula;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: You would save yourself a lot of work if you used an ORM and a [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx). I don't use Postgres but [this ORM](https://github.com/tumtumtum/Shaolinq) looks worth a try.